# Adobe InDesign black text being detected by printer as colour when exported to .pdf file

Tags: adobe-indesign

I print a small bulletin with 12 pages, the first is in colour, the rest is b&W text. When I export to .pdf the .pdf file is interpreted by the printer as black created by all the colours, not the straight black. Is there a way of exporting so that the black text stays black and is not printed as a colour page?

Comment: Does the PDF have registration, bleed, or trim marks?

Answer (score 1):

In general, straight black channel text will not be converted to 4 color black **unless** you have your InDesign preferences set incorrectly. **And Adobe has them *set incorrectly by default*.**

Choose `File > Preferences > Appearance of Black` from the menu in InDesign.

**Be certain to set the `Print/Exporting` option to "Output All Blacks Accurately".**

[image]

And then be certain your type is set with the *Black* swatch and **not** the *Registration* swatch by mistake.

This should then generate a PDF with straight black type as opposed to 4-color type.

Comment: All the settings as above has been confirmed in Indesign, but when the exported PDF is printed on a colour printer the text still prints as CMYK